# What's your favorite Prototype framework compatible, javascript date picker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, user-interface

Please one library per answer so that people can vote for the individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Calendar Date Select](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/)

Answer (score 3):

[Timeframe](http://stephencelis.com/projects/timeframe) for visual selection of date ranges...

Comment: @CMS Wow - Timeframe is really nice. I'd upvote twice if I could. I would say it rivals or bests the date range ui on google analytics.

Comment: Thanks micahwittman, it's a really really nice control :) ...

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery's UI.DatePicker](http://ui.jquery.com/repository/latest/demos/functional/#ui.datepicker)

*(Prototype compatible via JQuery.noConflict())*

Comment: Along with date, add formatted time: http://derekallard.com/blog/post/adding-time-to-jquery-ui-datepicker/

Answer (score 2):

[Scal](http://scal.fieldguidetoprogrammers.com/) is a simple, javascript calendar/date picker based on the Prototype JS library.

To create a calendar, just create an instance of scal with your base element and the update callback, along with optional parameters:

```
var cal = new scal('samplecal', updateelement, {
  oncalchange: function(d) {
    alert('Calendar Change: ' + d.format('yyyy-mm-dd'));
  }
});
```

Check out the [demo](http://scal.fieldguidetoprogrammers.com/scal-v02-documentation/scal-demo) and its [cookbook](http://scal.fieldguidetoprogrammers.com/scal-v02-documentation/scal-cookbook).

Comment: Both the demo and cookbook links return 404 errors at the moment.

Comment: Go for http://code.google.com/p/scaljs/ - The homepage is offline due to "Project home page was gobbled up by a worm. We are working to restore access to the docs and what not. In the meantime, the source code is available here in the DOWNLOADS tab."

Answer (score 1):

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is pretty cool, although it's  technically not a date picker per se.

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo! UI Library: Calendar](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/)

> "The Calendar component is a UI control
>   that enables users to choose one or
>   more dates from a graphical calendar
>   presented in a single month or multi
>   month interface. Calendars are
>   generated entirely via script and can
>   be navigated without any page
>   refreshes."
>
> "You'll find the Calendar Control to be
>   a useful and easy-to-implement
>   enhancement to any date-selection
>   interaction; you may also find that
>   the Calendar's foundation classes are
>   a good place to start for more complex
>   interfaces that visually organize
>   date-tagged information (like
>   appointments, photos, events, etc.)."

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS works well with Prototype and has a widgets that constantly gets extended by its community. DatePicker is one of them.

demo: http://www.lubber.de/extjs/datepickerplus/